# Press Print Screen on keyboard with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Is there a way to click a JavaScript button and that cause your computer to click the Print Screen button on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print screen does not have a key code because browsers limit the amount of control you have on a user's machine. To control the print screen function on any machine, you would need to install software on the user's machine.